# Problema con $_SESSION al utilizarlo en sistema de pin

Tags: php

He creado un sistema de seguridad donde el usuario con rango mayor y igual a 3 será enviado a una página /client_denied (pincode.php) y colocará su pin para ingresar al /client (client.php). Hasta ahí funciona, pero quiero que al usuario le salga dicha página para ingresar el pin siempre que entre al client.

Código PHP

```
// Código del client.php (/client)
else if($light->pin_enabled == true && !isset($_SESSION["Pincode_Passed"]) && $users->userVar(USERNAME, 'rank') >= 3) {
    header ("Location: " . WWW . "/client_denied");
}

// Código del pincode.php (client_denied)
$currentPin = $users->userVar(USERNAME, 'pincode'); // Pincode del usuario

if(isset($_POST["entered"])) {
    $pin = $_POST["key1"]; // POST del input para colocar el pin de acceso
    if($users->userVar(USERNAME, 'online') == "1"){ // Si está conectado mostrará este error
        $success = $light->errorMessage('Te encuentras conectado, ¿eres tú?...');
    }
        else{
    if($pin == $currentPin) { // Si el pin coincide lo llevará al /client
        $_SESSION["Pincode_Passed"] = true; // Dará $_SESSION verdadera
        header ("Location: " . WWW . "/client");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        $success = $light->errorMessage('El pin es inválido.'); // ERROR
    }
}
}
```

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La pregutna está un poco confusa, y faltaría ver el código de `cliente.php`.
Pero si la condición para mostrar la página `cliente.php` es que `$_SESSION['Pincode_Passed']` sea `true`, y querés que pida el pin cada vez que se va a acceder a la página, `$_SESSION['Pincode_Passed']` debe ser puesto nuevamente a `false` una vez que ingresaste a `cliente.php`.

De otro modo el `true` ya quedó seteado en la sesión y hasta que la misma no sea destruida no habría motivo para volver a pedir el pin.

En cliente.php fijate de modificar lo siguiente:

```
// para hacer la condición más fácil.
$pincode_passed = isset($_SESSION["Pincode_Passed"]) && $_SESSION["Pincode_Passed"] === true;
if ( ???) {
    (2)
    ...
} else if($light->pin_enabled === true && 
        $pincode_passed === false && 
        $users->userVar(USERNAME, 'rank') >= 3) {

    header ("Location: " . WWW . "/client_denied");
}
// Esto resetea el flag de pincode_passed.
$_SESSION["Pincode_Passed"] = false;  // (1)
```

(1) Esta linea que resetea el `Pincode_Passed` debe estar en la parte que se ejecuta si el usuario tiene el permiso para ingresar.

Como en la pregunta falta la mitad del `if-else` lo pongo fuera de la condición suponiendo que si no se da el `else`, esa parte se va a ejecutar.

Encambio si la parte del `if` es la que se ejecuta y nada más, esta línea iría donde esta esta marca: (2).

Comment: Comentarías un ejemplo del código editado, el código de ejemplo que puse en la publicación es todo referente al sistema de pin. Pero creo que el fallo está en el código php del client.php en **!isset($_SESSION["Pincode_Passed"])**, pero no lo logro resolverlo.

Comment: Fijate las modificaciones a la respuesta y en todo caso agrega, por lo menos, el if con la condición.

Comment: Gracias bro, ya está solucionado